# Can I add CSV to existing BiqQuery table without schema?

Tags: google-bigquery

When I have a table in BigQuery, and wanna add additional CSV data to it using `bq load`, can I do it without specifying schema?

If no, is the easiest way fetching the schema with

```
$ bq show --format=prettyjson <table>
```

and `bq load` using the schema?

I think that way is too lengthy, because BQ already knows the schema.
Is there any easier ways to add data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

This is one of my lazy data loading scripts, for example:

```
bq query --destination_table=dataset.new_table \
 'SELECT * FROM [dataset.old_table] LIMIT 0'     
bq load dataset.new_table gs://my/new_file.csv
```

Step 1 creates a new table with the same schema as an existing table (LIMIT 0 takes care of just copying the schema).

Step 2 loads data into it, and as the table already exists, there's no need to set the schema.

If you skip step 1 - it will append to any existing table.

Comment: Oh, `bq load dataset.new_table gs://my/new_file.csv` works? Then what I want is just `bq load dataset.old_table gs://my/new_file.csv`

Comment: Yeah. I gave you 2 lines so the answer wouldn't be just 1. Feel free to accept if it works!